# Query an AWS RDS Database(Mysql) through AWS API Gateway and Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-rds

So I have a RDS Database server running Mysql engine, Now I need to query into this database through my mobile app based on Flutter.
The solution after some research I came up with was to **create a Lambda function and hook it up to  RDS and API Gateway Service**. The deployed API would be used by the app.

But I need some help on this regarding how to set this up. Any good alternatives, reference materials or videos would be helpful.

**Can you help me out?**

Comment: Your mobile app would use a REST API that is running on API Gateway. In API GW you would proxy the request to a lambda function and that lambda function would perform the database operation

Comment: @LLL Thank you for the help, yes i'm currently working on that only, I'm now facing an Issue while executing the Lambda function via API Gateway (error "Internal Server Error"). But while testing the script inside the lambda function it works fine.

Comment: 30 minute tutorial on this - everything you need to know: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/query-your-aws-database-from-your-serverless-application/

Comment: Thank you @DeanaH., I'll go through it once.